# jQuery and AJAX not working after deployed to server

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a project that works fine on my local machine, but after its been deployed to the server, fails to work. If I put breakpoints in the javascript it hits them and goes through the code, but doesn't do what it's supposed to (jquery autocomplete). I've even made sure the script files I need are stored on the server. Is there something I'm over looking?

Code that needs to be run:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input.autocomplete").autocomplete({
            appendTo: '.container',
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/GetUsers',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { query: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item, value: item };
                        }));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

_Layout.cshtml page where jquery is included:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.autocomplete.css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js")"></script>
```

Comment: show the code. so that we can help.

Comment: Is it giving you any errors? This is fairly vague and no code is provided so it's going to be hard to tell.

Comment: You have overlooked actually posting your code in your question so that we might help.

Comment: sorry, accidentally hit submit too soon. Adding code

Comment: Probably a permission problem.

Comment: @MikeBrant I get no errors, it simply doesn't work. I've had this problem before but last time it was simply putting the jQuery files on the server.

Comment: When you say it "doesn't do what it's supposed to do"... what _does_ it do?  Is the code executed?  Is the AJAX call made?  What is the response from the server resource being accessed in the AJAX call?  How is that response handled?

Comment: @David From what it seems, when I open up the dev tools and place a breakpoint on that function it looks like it goes through the process of passing the data back to the server, however the autocomplete options never appear. I'm not super familiar with the innner workings of this so it's hard to tell when I'm stepping through it.

Comment: @Danger_Fox: In the browser debugging tools take a look at the network requests.  You should see the AJAX request being made to the server and see what the server's response is to that request.  For an auto-complete, you're expecting it to return with data of some kind.

Comment: @David After looking at that, it's saying it can't find "jquery-ui.autocomplete.css" However, if I look at the directory that it is looking for it in it is there

Comment: @Danger_Fox: Are you using `@Styles.Render` correctly?  I've only used it to render bundles, not directly render files.  In the first line you're rendering a bundle (which is configured in another file in the project), but in the next two you appear to be passing the files themselves directly to the method call.  Do those correspond to bundle configurations?

Comment: Clearing the browser cache solves my problem in 90% of the cases..

Comment: @David Looking at it some more, something it wrong with the post. When I run it locally it posts where it is supposed to ('Home/GetUsers'), however on the server it tries to post to 'Lookup/Home/('/Home/GetUsers')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to change the url to one that worked on the server. My final code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input.autocomplete").autocomplete({
        appendTo: '.container',
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Lookup/Home/GetUsers',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { query: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item, value: item };
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: Why did you need to add `/Lookup` to the url?

Answer (score 5):

i am also face this issue in my mvc project ....

i am solved this issue by following steps.

1) Put this in your Layout page in script section

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var RootUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")';
</script>
```

2) add the "RootUrl" variable in ajax url. (it's also working your Js File you add "RootUrl" before your ajax url)

```
 url: RootUrl +'Home/GetUsers';
```

It's working prefect for me but anyone have other solution then plz post me

Answer (score 2):

Although its a very old question , but this might help someone in future.

If its a .asmx page that is been developed then we have to specify the HTTP verbs in web.config to access it.

It will work in local but not after deployed on IIS.

EX:

```
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpGet"/>
      <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
  </webServices>
```

Thanks
Pooja G

Answer (score 2):

Having the same issue, ajax call not working after deploy to server. Amol's method is good for deployment, but that doesn't work on local development computer. You have to remove "~" when debugging on local development.

After some research, find a better solution can fits both environments. In your ajax method, change **URL** parameter to this way:

```
 url: "@Url.Action("GetUsers", "Home")"
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case server not supported to Url ,

Remove `'/Home/GetUsers'`

and use `url: "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")"`

Answer (score 0):

Use laravel named routes. e.g if route is '/Home/GetUsers',
in routes, web.php, assign it a name e.g ->name("home"),
then in ajax use:
URL: "{{ route('home') }}"